# Hikari and test on borrow option

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp, apache-commons-dbcp

I use spring boot 2 with `Hikari` connection pool, jpa and postgres.

Is there any reason to continue to use theses options

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle
```

Comment: Yes but not the `validationQuery` property, JDBC4 has out-of-the-box support for validation. No need to use a query for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum But Hikari doesn't have `testOnBorrow`  or `testWhileIdle` properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, They are unknown properties to [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) connection pool so no need ,

They exists only in [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) (used in old Spring boot) which you aren't using anymore.

[Explanation of different between properties](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/181)

> **DBCP** testOnBorrow=false rollbackOnReturn=false
> enableAutoCommitOnReturn=false
>
> **Issues:**
>
> testOnBorrow=false increases the likelihood of broken connections
> given to your application rollbackOnReturn=false +
> enableAutoCommitOnReturn=false, like the C3P0 "remediation" above can
> bleed transactions between consumers or cause locks to be held for
> extended periods
>
> **HikariCP Differentiators**
>
> Tests connections with isValid() before returning them from the pool,
> with an optimization that bypasses the check if the connection was
> utilized within the last 1000ms Tracks connection state (and
> transaction state), and performs rollback() only the the case of a
> non-autocommit connections with uncommitted changes